# Hoya care - will it ever flower again?

Tags: plant-care, flowering, perennials, repotting

Oh, the things I have done to my mother-in-law's Hoya plant:

- First, I watered it weekly. Neither the plant or the mother-in-law liked that.
- Then I had the audacity to re-pot the root bound mess. I can't win with this plant.

It needs a level of neglect that is too much for me. Not "has reached", but legitimately wants to be neglected. Rumor has it that it will not flower for two years after being re-potted. What is your experience? Is this true?

So my question is this: Will it take my Hoya 2-years to bloom after being re-potted? Or will it be sooner???

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: They don't like being repotted, so its usually only done when absolutely essential, but a photo would be useful - it should recover and flower again eventually, if you get the watering right

Comment: Added pictures.